# Why should we remove seasonality from a time series?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

While working with time series, we sometimes detect and remove seasonality using spectral analysis. I am a real beginner in time series, and I am confused why one would want to remove seasonality from the original time series? Doesn't removing seasonality distort the original data?

What benefits do we get by constructing a time series by removing the seasonality?

Comment: The final sentence of the opening paragraph of the wikipedia entry on [seasonal adjustment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonal_adjustment) gives a reason why governments (and other organizations that must deal with planning, including many businesses) might want to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Burman, J. Peter (1980), “[Seasonal Adjustment by Signal Extraction](http://www.jstor.org/discover/2982132?sid=21104976523991&uid=2&uid=3739256&uid=3739936&uid=4),” Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series A, 143, p.321

The reasons according to Burman:

> The most common is to provide an estimate of the current trend so
>   that judgemental short-term forecasts can be made. Alternatively, it
>   may be applied to a large number of series which enter an economic
>   model, as it has been found impracticable to use unadjusted data with
>   seasonal dummies in all but the smallest models: this is often called
>   the historical mode of seasonal adjustment

- Shiskin, Julius (1957), “[Electronic Computers and Business Indicators](http://www.nber.org/chapters/c2725.pdf)", Journal of Business, 30, 219-267.

> A principal purpose of studying economic indicators is to determine
>   the stage of the business cycle at which the economy stands. Such
>   knowledge helps in forecasting subsequent cyclical movements and
>   provides a factual basis for taking steps to moderate the amplitude
>   and scope of the business cycle. . . . In using indicators, however,
>   analysts are perennially troubled by the difficulty of separating
>   cyclical from other types of fluctuations, particularly seasonal
>   fluctuations.

If you want my 2 kopeks, then I'd summarize it like this:

1. Convenience: If you deal with multiple economic series, each of them will have its own seasonality. It becomes impractical to deal with seasonality of each series in multivariate models. So, it's easier to de-seasonalize all economic series before adding them to multivariate models, or analyzing them together.
2. Trend extraction: many economic series are inherently seasonal, e.g. house prices are higher in summer. Hence, when house price index suddenly goes down, it is not always because it signals something important in economy, but it could simply be the seasonal drop, which has no significant information. Hence, we want to deseasonalize the series to understand where we are.

Comment: if I am doing timeseries modeling, shouldn't the model also learn the seasonality and trends in the series?

Comment: There are many ways of doing tie series. You may leave the seasonality in the series, then explicitly deal with it in the lag structure with SARIMA, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so from your comment, I assume that we have to account for seasonality and trend in the modeling, but sometimes we remove them so that we can learn the underlying pattern and learn the seasonal part separately and combine. am I right?

Comment: yes, there is no one only way of modeling, you always have different options.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at relationships between two variables which are time series, seasonality will reduce the degrees of freedom because the data will not be independent. This "serial" correlation will result in spurious correlations.  Thus the seasonality is removed with the goal of increasing the degrees of freedom.

Comment: I think you might be making some valid arguments about time series but I don't understand your use of the term "degrees if freedom" in this context.

Comment: What I mean is the number of independent observations which will allow us to compute error bars to establish the significance of our correlations.

Comment: Okay. That is a different matter. Degrees of freedom is a technical statistical term that applies to t and F distributions.